# How can I get partition?

Tags: prolog

I am new on prolog and I want to list the n-ary partitions of a number in prolog using backtracking. The result must be something like this:

```
?- nary(3,9,P).
P = [9] ? ;
P = [3,3,3] ? ;
P = [3,3,1,1,1] ? ;
P = [3,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
P = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
no
```

Do you have any ideas of how to do it?
Lots of thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you mean n-ary partitions as described in [Characterizing the Number of m-ary Partitions Modulo m](https://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/%7Efraenkel/Papers/AndFraSel-I.pdf):

*... These are partitions of an integer n wherein each part is a power of a fixed integer m >= 2. ... As an example, note that there are five 3-ary partitions of n=9: 9, 3+3+3, 3+3+1+1+1, 3+1+1+1+1+1+1, 1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1. ...*

Note, that in the linked Paper the *m* corresponds to the *n* in your question. Building on `base_limit_powers/3` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72512119), I propose to keep using DCGs and CLP(FD). Let's start with a name for the predicate and the DCG, e.g. `nary_partitions_of/3` (Note that I swapped the second and third arguments of your predicate `nary/3` to more easily obtain a nice declarative name) and `partitions_//4`.

The second argument is a list (`Partitions`), consisting of powers of the first argument (`N`), that add up to the number that is the third argument (`Int`). The first number has to be greater or equal to 2 per definition (see above), hence the sum has to be as well. Since you want the powers in the list in descending order, the predicate `reverse/2` from `library(lists)` can be used to reorder the list of powers as described by `base_limit_powers/3` and have `partitions_//4` start with the largest number. Because of `N` and `Int` being larger than 1 the list of powers is not empty and its corresponding reversed list can be written in head and tail notation (`[FRP|RPs]`, read *F* irst of *R* eversed *P* owers and rest of *R* eversed *P* ower *s*), thereby providing easy access to the first (and largest) number (`FRP`) that is to be used as second argument of `partitions_//4`. At the time `partitions_//4` is called (using `phrase/2`), the list `Partitions` is yet to be described, therefore the sum of its numbers is still 0. Putting all this together the relation `nary_partitions_of/3` can be defined like so:

```
nary_partitions_of(N,Partitions,Int) :-
    N #> 1,
    Int #> 1,
    base_limit_powers(N,Int,Powers),
    reverse(Powers,[FRP|RPs]),
    phrase(partitions_([FRP|RPs],FRP,0,Int),Partitions).
```

Then the n-ary partitions can be described by a DCG like so:

```
partitions_(_Powers,_Last,Int,Int) --> % If the sum and the integer are equal
    [].                                % the list is finished
partitions_(Powers,Last,Sum0,Int) -->  % otherwise
    {Sum0 #< Int},                     % the sum is smaller than the integer and
    {P #=< Last},                      % the power to be added is less or equal to the last power in the partition and
    {member(P,Powers)},                % the power is from the list of powers and
    {Sum1 #= Sum0 + P},                % adds to the sum of powers so far and
    [P],                               % the power is in the list of partitions and
    partitions_(Powers,P,Sum1,Int).    % the remainder of the partition-list is described recursively
```

With this definition your example query produces the desired answers:

```
   ?- nary_partitions_of(3,P,9).
P = [9] ? ;
P = [3,3,3] ? ;
P = [3,3,1,1,1] ? ;
P = [3,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
P = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
no
```

Due to the use of CLP(FD) you can also use `nary_partitions_of/3` to ask different types of questions, e.g. to check if a given list is a partition of some `N` and `Int`, however this query loops after producing the answers:

```
   ?- nary_partitions_of(N,[9],Int).
Int = N = 9 ? ;
Int = 9,
N = 3 ? ;
% loop here
```

But due to the use of CLP(FD) that can be remedied by constraining the range of `N` like so:

```
   ?- N in 2..5, nary_partitions_of(N,[9],Int).
Int = 9,
N = 3 ? ;
no

   ?- N in 2..5, nary_partitions_of(N,[3,3,3],Int).
Int = 9,
N = 3 ? ;
no

   ?- N in 2..5, nary_partitions_of(N,[3,3,1,1,1],Int).
Int = 9,
N = 3 ? ;
no

   ?- N in 2..5, nary_partitions_of(N,[3,3,1,1],Int).
Int = 8,
N = 3 ? ;
no

   ?- N in 2..5, nary_partitions_of(N,[3,3,4],Int).
no
```

You can also look for n-ary partitions of some number, e.g. 9 without specifying `N`:

```
   ?- N in 2..6, nary_partitions_of(N,P,9).
N = 4,
P = [4,4,1] ? ;
N = 6,
P = [6,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 5,
P = [5,1,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 4,
P = [4,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
P = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
N in 3..6,                      % residual goal
N^2#=_A,                        % residual goal
_A in 10..36 ? ;                % residual goal
.
.
.
```

However this leads to some residual goals in the answers (see [CLP(FD) documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) for details). You can again remedy this by constraining `N`, this time also labeling it:

```
   ?- N in 2..6, nary_partitions_of(N,P,9), label([N]).
N = 4,
P = [4,4,1] ? ;
N = 6,
P = [6,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 5,
P = [5,1,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 4,
P = [4,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 4,
P = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 5,
P = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 6,
P = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 3,
P = [9] ? ;
N = 3,
P = [3,3,3] ? ;
N = 3,
P = [3,3,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 3,
P = [3,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 3,
P = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 2,
P = [8,1] ? ;
N = 2,
P = [4,4,1] ? ;
N = 2,
P = [4,2,2,1] ? ;
N = 2,
P = [4,2,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 2,
P = [4,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 2,
P = [2,2,2,2,1] ? ;
N = 2,
P = [2,2,2,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 2,
P = [2,2,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 2,
P = [2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
N = 2,
P = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
no
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this, where the nary partitions are either the number in a list, or it expanded (spand). Then the spand process takes the first number evenly divisible by the partition size, splits the list on it, inserts the partition, and either completes there OR spands the newly constructed complete list on backtracking.

This was about the only way I could get your backtracking request without the backtracking undoing the previous expansion and turning 1,1,1 back into 3. I haven't been able to split the list on the first evenly divisible element without leaving any choicepoints in a nicer way, but there probably is a nicer way.

```
spand(In, Psize, Out) :-
    once((append(Left, [Elem|Right], In),  % first divisible element, e.g. 3
          0 is Elem mod Psize)),
    
    length(Parts, Psize),    % make the partition list, e.g. [1,1,1]
    Pt is Elem / Psize,
    maplist(=(Pt), Parts),
    append(Left, Parts, Temp),
    
    ( append(Temp, Right, Out)    % choicepoint for backtracking
    ; append(Temp, Right, Out_),
      spand(Out_, Psize, Out)).

nary(Psize, Target, Parts) :-
    Parts = [Target]
    ;
    spand([Target], Psize, Parts).
```

e.g.

```
?- nary(3, 9, Parts).
Parts = [9] ;
Parts = [3, 3, 3] ;
Parts = [1, 1, 1, 3, 3] ;
Parts = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3] ;
Parts = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
false
```

e.g.

```
?- nary(2, 24, Parts).
Parts = [24] ;
Parts = [12, 12] ;
Parts = [6, 6, 12] ;
Parts = [3, 3, 6, 12] ;
Parts = [3, 3, 3, 3, 12] ;
Parts = [3, 3, 3, 3, 6, 6] ;
Parts = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 6] ;
Parts = [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3] ;
false
```

Your example is too short to see if `[6, 6, 12]` -> `[3, 3, 6, 12]` or `[6, 6, 6, 6]`. Depth first or Breadth first.

Comment: Thanks you so much that helps me a lot to improve in prolog!

Comment: One more question: How could you sort the result, so that shorter lists appear first?

Comment: @javiLPot I don't understand, this looks like shorter lists appear first as it is now? If you mean larger numbers appear first, probably with `reverse/2` inside `nary`