# How can I get a list of the powers of X less-than or equal to N in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I am trying to learn more about prolog and I want to get a list of the powers of a certain number X less-than or equal to a number N.
The result need to be something like this:

```
?- powers (5,123,List).
List = [25,5,1] ? ;
no
```

Thanks you so much!

Comment: Hints: Loop, starting at power 0, until the power is greater than 123. Add to the list at the *end* of the predicate, to result in reverse order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
powers(N, MaxP, Lst) :-
    % Start with empty list, to create list in descending order
    powers_(N, MaxP, 1, [], Lst).
    
powers_(N, MaxP, Upto, LstUpto, Lst) :-
    Upto =< MaxP,
    % Don't backtrack to the "finished" alternative
    !,
    Upto1 is Upto * N,
    % Loop, adding to list in reverse order
    powers_(N, MaxP, Upto1, [Upto|LstUpto], Lst).

% Finished - unify Lst
powers_(_N, _MaxP, _Upto, Lst, Lst).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(powers(5, 123, L)).
% 12 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (49% CPU, 216353 Lips)
L = [25,5,1].
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to describe a list, I would recommend the use of DCGs. And because you're working with integers the use of the CLP(FD) library would be opportune. Let's start with picking a nice declarative name for the predicate and the DCG, e.g. `base_limit_powers/3` and `powers_//3`. For starters, let's describe the list of powers in ascending order:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)). % use CLP(FD)

powers_(Base,Limit,Exp) -->    
    {Pow #= Base ^ Exp},       
    {Pow #> Limit},            % if the power is larger than the limit
    [].                        % it is not in the list anymore
powers_(Base,Limit,Exp0) -->
    {Pow #= Base ^ Exp0},
    {Pow #=< Limit},           % if the power is less then or equal to the limit
    {Exp1 #= Exp0 + 1},        
    [Pow],                     % it is in the list
    powers_(Base,Limit,Exp1).  % continue with the increased exponent

base_limit_powers(B,L,P) :-
    phrase(powers_(B,L,0),P).  % use phrase/2 to call powers//3 with 0 as the first exponent
```

Regular Prolog-goals can be used in DCGs if they are enclosed in `{}`. For details on the constraints `#=/2`, `#>/2` and `#=</2` and `library(clpfd)` in general see the [CLP(FD) documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html). Now let's start to look at some queries, starting with your given example:

```
   ?- base_limit_powers(5,123,P). % What are the powers of 5 less than or equal to 123?
P = [1,5,25] ? ;
no
```

That works as intended. However, due to the use of CLP(FD), the predicate can also be used in other ways as well:

```
   ?- base_limit_powers(5,L,P). % What are the powers of 5 without a specified limit?
P = [],                         % There are no powers
L in inf..0 ? ;                 % with limits from minus infinity to 0
P = [1],                        % there's one power
L in 1..4 ? ;                   % if the limit is between 1 and 4
P = [1,5],                      % there are two powers
L in 5..24 ? ;                  % if the limit is between 5 and 24
P = [1,5,25],                   % there are three powers
L in 25..124 ? ;                % if the limit is between 25 and 124
P = [1,5,25,125],               % there are four powers
L in 125..624 ?;                % if the limit is between 125 and 624
.
.
.
```

You can also leave the first and the third arguments variable, but in order to get actual numbers as answers instead of residual goals (see [CLP(FD) documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html) for details) you have to constrain `X` to an interval and label it:

```
   ?- X in 2..5, base_limit_powers(X,123,P), label([X]). % What powers up to 123 are there with a base between 2 and 5?
P = [1,5,25],             % there are 3 powers
X = 5 ? ;                 % with the base 5
P = [1,4,16,64],          % there are 4 powers
X = 4 ? ;                 % with the base 4
P = [1,3,9,27,81],        % there are 5 powers
X = 3 ? ;                 % with the base 3
P = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64],   % there are 6 powers
X = 2 ? ;                 % with the base 2
no
```

You can also check if a list of numbers are powers of some base:

```
   ?- base_limit_powers(B,L,[1,5,25]). % Is [1,5,25] a list of powers?
B = 5,                                 % Yes, with the base being 5
L in 25..124 ? ;                       % and a limit between 25 and 124
no
   ?- base_limit_powers(B,L,[1,2,3]).  % Is [1,2,3] a list of powers?
no
```

Now let's turn to your example query with the powers in descending order. At first glance the obvious choice for a change seems to be simply flipping two goals:

```
powers2_(Base,Limit,Exp) -->
    {Pow #= Base ^ Exp},
    {Pow #> Limit},
    [].
powers2_(Base,Limit,Exp0) -->
    {Pow #= Base ^ Exp0},
    {Pow #=< Limit},
    {Exp1 #= Exp0 + 1},
    powers2_(Base,Limit,Exp1),   % these two goals
    [Pow].                       % have been flipped

base_limit_powers2(B,L,P) :-
    phrase(powers2_(B,L,0),P).
```

And the first three queries are indeed working as expected:

```
   ?- base_limit_powers2(5,123,P).
P = [25,5,1] ? ;
no

   ?- base_limit_powers2(5,L,P).
P = [],
L in inf..0 ? ;
P = [1],
L in 1..4 ? ;
P = [5,1],
L in 5..24 ? ;
P = [25,5,1],
L in 25..124 ? ;
P = [125,25,5,1],
L in 125..624 ? ; 
.
.
.

   ?- X in 2..5, base_limit_powers2(X,123,P), label([X]).
P = [25,5,1],
X = 5 ? ;
P = [64,16,4,1],
X = 4 ? ;
P = [81,27,9,3,1],
X = 3 ? ;
P = [64,32,16,8,4,2,1],
X = 2 ? ;
no
```

The fourth query, however, is now looping after producing the correct answer:

```
   ?- base_limit_powers2(B,L,[25,5,1]).
B = 5,
L in 25..124 ? ;
```

The fifth query is even looping without ever terminating:

```
?- base_limit_powers2(B,L,[3,2,1]).
```

This is due to the reordering of the two goals in the second version, putting the recursive goal first. So this brings the first version back into play. If you get the list of powers in descending order as an answer from some other predicate (in the examples below, the goal `P=[...]` is used in place of such a predicate), you can use the predicate `reverse/2` from `library(lists)` (or write your own version of it) to reorder the list for use with `base_limit_powers/3`:

```
   ?- P=[25,5,1], reverse(P,PR), base_limit_powers(B,L,PR).
B = 5,
P = [25,5,1],
PR = [1,5,25],
L in 25..124 ? ;
no

   ?- P=[3,2,1], reverse(P,PR), base_limit_powers(B,L,PR).
no
```

On the other hand, for queries that leave the third argument variable, you can use a goal `reverse/2` after calling `base_limit_powers/3` to reorder the list of powers:

```
   ?- base_limit_powers(5,123,P), reverse(P,PR).
P = [1,5,25],
PR = [25,5,1] ? ;
no

   ?- base_limit_powers(5,L,P), reverse(P,PR).
P = PR = [],
L in inf..0 ? ;
P = PR = [1],
L in 1..4 ? ;
P = [1,5],
PR = [5,1],
L in 5..24 ? ;
P = [1,5,25],
PR = [25,5,1],
L in 25..124 ? ;
P = [1,5,25,125],
PR = [125,25,5,1],
L in 125..624 ? ;
.
.
.

   ?- X in 2..5, base_limit_powers(X,123,P), label([X]), reverse(P,PR).
P = [1,5,25],
PR = [25,5,1],
X = 5 ? ;
P = [1,4,16,64],
PR = [64,16,4,1],
X = 4 ? ;
P = [1,3,9,27,81],
PR = [81,27,9,3,1],
X = 3 ? ;
P = [1,2,4,8,16,32,64],
PR = [64,32,16,8,4,2,1],
X = 2 ? ;
no
```

Comment: A minor aside: Do you know `(#)/1`?

Comment: @false: Do you by any chance mean `(#)/1` from [clpz.pl](https://github.com/triska/clpz/blob/master/clpz.pl)? If yes, I'm not familiar with it. At least yet...

Comment: In case you use SWI you need `op(150, fx, #)` to make it more readable. Then you can write `#X + #Y #= #Z`

Answer (score 0):

```
pow(Base, Exp, X) :-
    X is Base ^ Exp.

powers(Base, Limit, Powers) :-
    NumExponents is floor(log10(1+Limit)/log10(Base)),
    numlist(0, NumExponents, Exponents),
    reverse(Exponents, ExponentsRev),
    maplist(pow(Base), ExponentsRev, Powers).
```

The powers will always start `5^0, 5^1, 5^2, ...` so if we knew how many there were we could make a list of exponents `[0,1,2,3]` and raise 5 to all of them and have the answer list with no explicit looping or testing. We can calculate how many there are using logarithms, and [work it out for base-5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base). e.g.

```
?- time(powers(5, 123, Powers))
% 29 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (168% CPU, 860534 Lips)
Powers = [25, 5, 1]
```