# How to do partitions on ISO-Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I've recently started with ISO-Prolog and I am only able to use predicates defined by
`:-module(_,_,[classic,assertions,regtypes]).` No call/2 o multimap.

I wanted to implement a program which creates N-ary partitions such as the one below:

```
?- nary(3,9,P).
P = [9] ? ;
P = [3,3,3] ? ;
P = [3,3,1,1,1] ? ;
P = [3,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
P = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1] ? ;
no
```

Any help is really welcome. Thank you.

Comment: What systems permits `:-module(_,_,...`?

Comment: Iso-prolog, using ciao-prolog to ask the questions. However, the only restrictions that supposes is not being able to use some predefined predicates such as call/(above 1) or multimaps. It allows first order clauses i believe, such as append or reverse.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72296377/how-can-i-get-partition)